# How to Export-CSV of Active Directory Objects?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get a dump of all user records and their associated groups for a user ID revalidation effort. My security officer wants it in CSV format.

This works great:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmailAddress,LastLogonDate,Manager,Title,Department,whenCreated,Enabled,Organization | Sort-Object -Property Name | ConvertTo-CSV
```

However, that does not include the groups the user is a member of.

Attempts at something like this have failed:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmailAddress,LastLogonDate,Manager,Title,Department,whenCreated,Enabled,Organization, @{$_.MemberOf |Get-Group|ForEach-Object {$_.Name}} | Sort-Object -Property Name | ConvertTo-CSV
```

This also failed:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Sort-Object -Property Name | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Format-List -Property Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmailAddress,LastLogonDate,Manager,Title,Department,whenCreated,Enabled
    $_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | ForEach-Object {$_.Name} | Sort-Object
}  | ConvertTo-CSV
```

I'm probably missing something simple.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: what operating system are you using? Windows Server?

Answer (score 8):

From a Windows Server OS execute the following command for a dump of the entire Active Director:

```
csvde -f test.csv
```

This command is very broad and will give you more than necessary information.  To constrain the records to only user records, you would instead want:

```
csvde -f test.csv -r objectClass=user
```

You can further restrict the command to give you only the fields you need relevant to the search requested such as:

```
csvde -f test.csv -r objectClass=user -l DN, sAMAccountName, department, memberOf
```

If you have an Exchange server and each user associated with a live person has a mailbox (as opposed to generic accounts for kiosk / lab workstations) you can use mailNickname in place of sAMAccountName.

Answer (score 7):

For posterity....I figured out how to get what I needed. Here it is in case it might be useful to somebody else.

```
$alist = "Name`tAccountName`tDescription`tEmailAddress`tLastLogonDate`tManager`tTitle`tDepartment`tCompany`twhenCreated`tAcctEnabled`tGroups`n"
$userlist = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmailAddress,LastLogonDate,Manager,Title,Department,Company,whenCreated,Enabled,MemberOf | Sort-Object -Property Name
$userlist | ForEach-Object {
    $grps = $_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | ForEach-Object {$_.Name} | Sort-Object
    $arec = $_.Name,$_.SamAccountName,$_.Description,$_.EmailAddress,$_LastLogonDate,$_.Manager,$_.Title,$_.Department,$_.Company,$_.whenCreated,$_.Enabled
    $aline = ($arec -join "`t") + "`t" + ($grps -join "`t") + "`n"
    $alist += $aline
}
$alist | Out-File D:\Temp\ADUsers.csv
```

Comment: any chance you can comment what each line does or reference a site that shows the information? Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 6):

```
csvde -f test.csv
```

This command will perform a CSV dump of every entry in your Active Directory server. You should be able to see the full DN's of users and groups.

You will have to go through that output file and get rid off the unnecessary content.

Comment: Our operation is trying to standardize on Powershell whenever possible.  I can pull the info I need, I am just having troubles getting the user fields and the user's group membership to appear on the same line in the CSV file.....so 1 user is 1 record.

Answer (score 1):

HI you can try this...

Try..

```
$Ad = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=OUi,DC=company,DC=com"  -Filter * -Properties employeeNumber | ? {$_.employeenumber -eq ""}
$Ad | Sort-Object -Property sn, givenName | Select * | Export-Csv c:\scripts\ceridian\NoClockNumber_2013_02_12.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Or

```
$Ad = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=OUi,DC=company,DC=com"  -Filter * -Properties employeeNumber | ? {$_.employeenumber -eq $null}
$Ad | Sort-Object -Property sn, givenName | Select * | Export-Csv c:\scripts\cer
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

***the first command is correct but change from convert to export to csv, as below,***

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * `
    | Select-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmailAddress,LastLogonDate,Manager,Title,Department,whenCreated,Enabled,Organization `
    | Sort-Object -Property Name `
    | Export-Csv -path  C:\Users\*\Desktop\file1.csv
```